# Resize images and them apply Masonry to them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to re-size some images which has default `width` and `height` set to `400px` and `300px`. For that I'm using this code:

```
var ids = new Array();
var tiw = ['200','300'];
var tih = ['150','200'];
jQuery('.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box').each(function(index) {
    ids[index] = jQuery(this).attr('id');
});

function shuffle(o){ //v1.0
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};
ids = shuffle(ids);

j = 0;
jQuery.each(ids,function(i, val){
    j = (j>2)?0:j;
    jQuery('#'+val).find('img').width(tiw[j]).height(tih[j]);
    j++;
});

var $container = $('.ngg-galleryoverview');

$container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box'
});
```

For some reason, some images maintain the default values and I don't want that since I can't handle after with [masonry jquery plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com). You can take live example [here](http://ismaelcala.com/) can any give me suggestions or a better solution? What I need to achieve is resize the defaults values to another values in order to get masonry working better than now

Comment: I don't see it working right now, is it ? have you tried this: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: @Ani basically is the same and I need to pay for it in case I'm using in a commercial site like this